Get Big Object Indexes via Apex
My company has decided on using Big Objects to archive data and I'm working on an LWC component that will allow a user to view/query Big Object records. We will have multiple Big Objects, so I'm trying to build the component such that it can dynamically adjust it's filters depending on the object's indexes.
My issue is, I cannot seem to find a way to get the index fields via Apex to make it happen. I've tried...

Using Schema.getGlobalDescribe(). I can find the Big Object but it doesn't seem to store the index anywhere.
Querying the CustomObject object via the tooling API, but it says that the Indexes field doesn't exist (even though it is listed as a field in the API Guide).
Checking the FieldDefinition Object, but index isn't stored there either.

There has to be a way as I can see the indexed field in the Big Object's metadata XML, but I can't seem to find a way to get the index via any Apex code.
        <fullName>EmailIndex</fullName>
        <fields>
            <name>FromAddress__c</name>
            <sortDirection>ASC</sortDirection>
        </fields>
        <fields>
            <name>EmailUniqueId__c</name>
            <sortDirection>ASC</sortDirection>
        </fields>
        <label>EmailIndex</label>
    </indexes>
    <label>ArchivedEmail</label>
    <pluralLabel>ArchivedEmails</pluralLabel> 

